# Another way, to storing handle 2 keys in map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Currently i use try to develop player's inventory system.
And I store items in 2 maps.
First map store pointer to item and as key use order short (game client use it in packets, its enumerator of inventory's item).

```
std::map<short, Item*> item_container;
```

Second map have same function, but it store item position in inventory (X and Y axis), what is needed to perform security check of item collision.
It's also stored as

```
std::map<short, Item*> item_container2;
```

And key is calculated by X axis * 100 + Y axis.
Also item class contains item X axis, item Y axis, and item sequence/enumerator/order.
I would to ask, how to simplify that to one map, because using 2 is little bit unsafe.
Thanks!

Comment: You want to have one only map, that's clear. What do you want to look up your values by (id? positon? any other property?)? That should be the key. The rest of the problem I don't undertand. X and Y are already attributes of Item? If so, I don't see the need for the second map.

Comment: Hey, i want also to iterate over X and Y to detect for item collision in inventory when client is use hack.

Comment: @user3126089 So keys in both containers are different ? Because I got a little confused.

Comment: @prajmus yeah, 1st container store order of item (1 , 2 , 3 ...), sacond store in inventory X * 100 + Y position.